# How to add month and year for 100 years in Oracle SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where column are

```
record, month, year, startdate, enddate
```

and I need to insert data such as

- first row as => 0, Jan, 1970, 01/01/1970, 31/01/1970
- second row as => 1, Feb, 1970, 01/02/1970, 28/02/1970

Note: special case should also consider leap year and then the `endate` for Feb should be 29.

Comment: What have you tried so far - did you get any errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use virtual columns in the table and derive `enddate`, `month` and `year` from `startdate`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  record    NUMBER,
  startdate DATE,
  enddate   DATE
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS (LAST_DAY(startdate)),
  month     VARCHAR2(3)
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
              CAST(
                TO_CHAR(startdate, 'MON', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English')
                AS VARCHAR2(3)
              )
            ),
  year      NUMBER(4,0)
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM startdate))
);
```

Then, if you want to insert 100 years of months then:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (record, startdate)
SELECT 0, ADD_MONTHS(DATE '1970-01-01', LEVEL - 1)
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12 * 100
```

and the table will contain:

| RECORD | STARTDATE | ENDDATE | MONTH | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | 1970-01-31 00:00:00 | JAN | 1970 |
| 0 | 1970-02-01 00:00:00 | 1970-02-28 00:00:00 | FEB | 1970 |
| 0 | 1970-03-01 00:00:00 | 1970-03-31 00:00:00 | MAR | 1970 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 0 | 2069-10-01 00:00:00 | 2069-10-31 00:00:00 | OCT | 2069 |
| 0 | 2069-11-01 00:00:00 | 2069-11-30 00:00:00 | NOV | 2069 |
| 0 | 2069-12-01 00:00:00 | 2069-12-31 00:00:00 | DEC | 2069 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gdiDJsIp)

Comment: If this is a lookup table in a data warehouse db, I'd argue that it would be better for performance if all the columns in the table were populated, rather than derived when queried.

Comment: @Boneist If that was the case then all the OP needs to do is remove the `GENERATED ALWAYS AS (...)` parts of the DDL statement and put those same queries it uses to derive the columns into the `INSERT` statement to persist the data.

Comment: @MTO is there a ways to just add record, months and year in table with out startdate and enddate, i mean i only want month and year for 100 years to be populate and will remove the columns startdate and enddate

Comment: can you suggest the updated query for that @MTO

Comment: @shashikantkuswaha Exactly as previously said, remove the `GENERATED AS ALWAYS` clauses from the DDL and put the same code into the `INSERT` statement. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DSh4HAYb). If you don't want `startdate` and `enddate` then don't include those in the `CREATE` table or in the `INSERT` (but you will still want to derive the year and month from a `DATE`).

Comment: yes, i did that and it is working thanks @MTO

Comment: @MTO, i have 1 question . Since DB schemas follow date formats based on time zones and this may fail if the format is not 'YYYY-MM-DD'. 
```INSERT INTO table_name (record, startdate)
SELECT 0, ADD_MONTHS(DATE '1970-01-01', LEVEL - 1)
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12 * 100```

Comment: @MTO do you think we need to use  ```ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'MM/DD/YYYY'), LEVEL - 1)``` please suggest ?

Comment: @shashikantkuswaha `DATE '1970-01-01'` is a date literal, it has its own specific format `YYYY-MM-DD` and **ALWAYS** uses that format irrespective of what the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is set to in the user's session so it will **ALWAYS** work. You do not need to use `TO_DATE` but it is an option if you want to.

Comment: ok, Thanks for the explaination. it really helped

Comment: @MTO , can we update the insert script to insert the month and year as well, and remove the GENERATED from create table script.
if YES then how will be the insert script look like ?

Comment: @shashikantkuswaha You can (but I would question whether you should as then you have month and year data that is derived from another column but could get out of sync). Just remove the `GENERATED BY` clauses from the `CREATE TABLE` statement and use the same `TO_CHAR` and `EXTRACT` statements that were removed from the `CREATE TABLE` statement in the `INSERT` statement instead for the appropriate columns.